# PushTopic query: triggering an event based on a roll-up summary field

Tags: roll-up-summary, streaming-api, pushtopic

I recently tried to add a roll-up summary field on a PushTopic query but I don't receive an event with the update when a change triggers a recalculation of the roll-up summary field value.

Do changes to roll-up summary fields trigger events via PushTopic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an already logged support case on this ask according to which the concerned Salesforce Product Development team has filed a documentation bug to reflect that `Rollup summary fields aren't supported for PushTopic events.If a PushTopic query contains a rollup summary field (RSF) for an object, notifications won't be sent for changes (create, update, delete, and undelete) in the RSF` in [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/unsupported_soql_statements.htm)

The workaround you are currently following is to create a DateTime field and update that field if the roll-up summary field changes.

Comment: I haven't actually logged a support case about this but thank you for the response. It would be helpful if the doc mentioned that roll up summary fields are also not supported along with formula fields